# Solve in the positive real number the system of equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve in the positive real numbers, the system of equations :
$$(2x)^{2013} + (2y)^{2013} + (2z)^{2013} =3 $$
and $$xy + yz + zx + 2xyz = 1.$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit , @julien but can you tell me how did you break the lines?

Comment: apart from (1/2, 1/2, 1/2), I imagine :-)

Comment: To get an equation centered on a single line, put it between double dollar sign, instead of single dollar.

Comment: Ok! Thanks @julien I would take care of it from now.

Comment: @julien, I'm about to remove the differential-geometry tag, since Ivan's solution makes it clear that that subject doesn't enter into it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{a}{2}, y=\frac{b}{2}, z=\frac{c}{2}$, so

$$ab+bc+ca+abc=4, a^{2013}+b^{2013}+c^{2013}=3$$

Now by A.M.$\geq$G.M. $4=ab+bc+ca+abc \geq 3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}+abc$. Let $x=\sqrt[3]{abc}$, so that $4 \geq 3x^2+x^3$.

Factorising, we get $(x-1)(x+2)^2 \leq 0$, so $x \leq 1$. Thus $abc \leq 1$, so $ab+ac+bc=4-abc \geq 3$.

Now by power mean inequality and the inequality $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq ab+ac+bc$ (which is equivalent to $\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2) \geq 0$), we get

$$1=\sqrt[2013]{\frac{a^{2013}+b^{2013}+c^{2013}}{3}} \geq \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}} \geq \sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+ca}{3}} \geq 1$$

Since equality holds, we must have $a=b=c$, so $3=3a^{2013}$ and we get $a=b=c=1$.

Therefore the only solution in positive reals is $(x, y, z)=(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: Nicely done, +1.